# Statistical Mode over Window in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, pyspark, count, statistical-mode

Spark doesn't implement a statistical mode function, therefore, one needs to cope with count and group by clauses to work around this.

In the case where one needs to calculate the statistical mode of a column over a given window, how can it be done without resorting to UDFs? Which would be the performance costs incurred?